# How to make adaptive UI on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to make adaptive UI for the different screen sizes of devices on XF?

Now I use Grid.

I set up RowHeight and ColumnWidth by using '*'.

For example,

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="2.3*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3.1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

But I can't make font size to be adaptive.

XF has font size options(Small, Large, Medium and Micro).

For example

```
 <Label
     HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
      Grid.Column="3"
      Grid.Row="2"
      TextColor="White"
      FontSize="Small"/>
```

But this way is not so flexible as I need.

How can I make font size to be adaptive?

Are there any other ways to make adaptive UI for the different screen size of device?

Comment: How adaptive do you need? There is an OnIdion for handling differences between tablet and phone, but it's not very granular -https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.OnIdiom%3CT%3E/

Comment: @JimBobBennett Each phone has different screen size. For example, iPhone 4 and iPhone 6, phone with Android can has 4,5 size of screen or 5,2 size screen. But I need same proportions of UI for each phone.